# Sql Alchemy can't cast jsonb to boolean

Tags: python, casting, sqlalchemy

I have the following value I'm pulling from a model, and trying to cast to a boolean. However, when I run the program I get an error stating `can't cast jsonb type to boolean. The value for the jsonb value here is a boolean, so why can't it cast it? What do I need to change?

The data value that I'm trying to get is the boolean out of `{"unsubscribe" : "True"}`

Here is the line that causes the error.

`args.append(Customer.data['unsubscribed'].cast(sqlalchemy.Boolean) == "{}".format(True))`

Here is the customer model

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, server_default='uuid_generate_v4()')
    phone_number = Column(String)
    data = Column(JSONB)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default='NOW()')
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, server_default='NOW()')

    @property
    def agent_number(self):
        return self.data["agent"]["phoneNumber"]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Customer(id={}, phone_number={}, data={}, created_at={}, updated_at={})>'.format(
            self.id,
            self.phone_number,
            self.data,
            self.created_at,
            self.updated_at
        )
```

Comment: I think the proper JSON there would be `{"unsubscribe": true}`, so it's not really a boolean... you'll need to cast to string instead, and compare as a string.

Comment: but `data['unsubscribe']` would return a boolean `true` wouldn't it?

Comment: surely there must be someway to just get the boolean value

Comment: It's not a boolean, it's a string... have you tried just leaving the cast out?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as PostgreSQL is concerned, the `true` is a `jsonb` type, not a SQL `boolean` type. You can't do

```
SELECT 'true'::jsonb::boolean;
```

You also can't do

```
SELECT '123'::jsonb::int;
```

You'll need to do some sort of conversion. One way is to convert to `varchar` using `->>`:

```
SELECT (('{"unsubscribed": true}'::jsonb)->>'unsubscribed')::boolean;
```

Or, you can use [`jsonb_to_record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
SELECT unsubscribed FROM jsonb_to_record('{"unsubscribed": true}'::jsonb) AS o(unsubscribed boolean);
```

As far as SQLAlchemy is concerned, you can do

```
Customer.data['unsubscribed'].astext.cast(sqlalchemy.Boolean).is_(True)
```

Or, go the other way

```
Customer.data['unsubscribed'] == cast('true', JSONB)
```